# Where can I find the transcripts of anime episodes online?

Tags: resources

I am looking around the internet for the transcripts for anime series and their episodes but cannot find one in particular for Attack on Titans.

I was searching around the internet for a while and couldn't find some sites. Does anyone know a website that does/contains the transcripts for anime series and their episodes? If not, I would like specifically a site for Attack on Titans episodes.

This would be useful I think for example you are answering a question and would like to add a certain spoken scene from an anime episode, and instead of watching the entire episode or skipping to that scene and playing and pausing the scene over and over again just to type out what they are saying, you can simply just have a look at the transcript and copy and paste it.

I know I might be lazy, but I think it would be extremely helpful. Anyone know any sites?

Comment: look for subtitle extensions on google, like `filetype:srt`, `filetype:ssa`, `filetype:ass attack on titan episode 6` [(example)](https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype%3Aass+attack+on+titan+episode+6).

Comment: Most subtitles are soft-subs, so you could also simply extract them from the MKV container :)

Comment: Yeah, or that ^. Just extract all subs with a batch script from a folder of mkv files and search for text.

Comment: @user1306322- I just tried that now. I should have tried it yesterday when I saw your comment but when I open up the .ass file it is just filled with gibberish. I thought it was another language, but Google just thinks its english. xD

Comment: Also when I tried the others such as filetype:srt attack on titans episode 19, I get linked to rubbish websites that won't let me download anything.

Comment: Like this site > http://www.subtitles.at/shingeki+no+kyojin+.srt

Comment: mkvtoolnix can be used to extract streams, subtitles and audio. The resulting subtitle can then be loaded into Aegisub and exported into whatever format you prefer.

Comment: .ass files are human-readable text file as far as I have messed with it. Check the encoding settings of your text editor.

Answer (score -1):

http://animetranscripts.wikispaces.com/Attack+on+Titan+-+%E9%80%B2%E6%92%83%E3%81%AE%E5%B7%A8%E4%BA%BA

It's not there for every episode though... I'll try some digging around.

http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/episode_scripts.php?tv-show=attack-on-titan-2013
No names though. Just the lines.